# ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYUSER.ADI_PK) violated

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables, `adv_institution` and `institution`. `institution` has 5000+ rows, while `adv_institution` has 1400+

I want to use Oracle MERGE to back-fill records to `adv_institution` from `institution`. These two tables have about four fields tin common which I can use to back-fill.

Here is my entire MERGE statement

```
merge into
  adv_institution to_t
using (
  select
    uni.*,
    adv_c.country_cd as con_code_text
  from
    (
      select 
        institution_cd, 
        name,
        institution_status,
        country_cd
      from 
        institution uni
      where
        uni.institution_status = 'ACTIVE' and
        uni.country_cd is not null
      group by
        institution_cd,
        name,
        institution_status,
        country_cd
      order by
        name  
    ) uni,
    country_cd c_cd,
    adv_country adv_c
  where
    uni.country_cd = c_cd.country_cd and
    c_cd.description = adv_c.country_cd
) from_t
on
(
  to_t.VENDOR_INSTITUTION_CD = from_t.INSTITUTION_CD or
  to_t.INSTITUTION_CD = from_t.NAME
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  to_t.INSTITUTION_CD,
  to_t.INSTITUTION_NAME,
  to_t.SHORT_NAME,
  to_t.COUNTRY_CD,

  to_t.NOTE,
  to_t.UNIT_TERMINOLOGY,
  to_t.COURSE_TERMINOLOGY,
  to_t.CLOSED_IND,

  to_t.UPDATE_WHO,
  to_t.UPDATE_ON,
  to_t.CALLISTA_INSTITUTION_CD
)
VALUES (
  from_t.NAME,
  from_t.NAME,
  '',
  from_t.con_code_text,

  '',
  'UNIT',
  'COURSE',
  'N',

  'MYUSER',
  SYSDATE,
  from_t.institution_cd
);
```

The error I got is

**Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYUSER.ADI_PK) violated**

`ADI_PK` means `adv_institution.institution_cd` is a primary key and it must be unique.

That is because in `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT` there is an insert statement. I insert `from_t.NAME` into `to_t.INSTITUTION_CD`.

It looks like `from_t.NAME` has the same value at least twice, when inserting into `to_t.INSTITUTION_CD`

But I did a group statement to make sure `from_t.NAME` is unique:

```
(
      select 
        institution_cd, 
        name,
        institution_status,
        country_cd
      from 
        institution uni
      where
        uni.institution_status = 'ACTIVE' and
        uni.country_cd is not null
      group by
        institution_cd,
        name,
        institution_status,
        country_cd
      order by
        name  
    ) uni
```

I am not sure I understand the issue correctly. I tried all I can, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is with group by.

**Please consider below example:**

```
 desc temp_inventory;
 Name                  Type
 --------------------- -----------
 WAREHOUSE_NO          NUMBER(2)
 ITEM_NO               NUMBER(10)
 ITEM_QUANTITY         NUMBER(10)

WAREHOUSE_NO    ITEM_NO    ITEM_QUANTITY
1               1000       100
1               2000       200
1               2000       300
```

If i write a query where I want warehouse_no to be unique:

```
select warehouse_no,item_quantity 
from temp_inventory 
group by warehouse_no,item_quantity
```

Its going to return the same 3 rows.. instead i want to group by..

```
select warehouse_no,sum(item_quantity)
from temp_inventory 
group by warehouse_no
```

which will make the warehouse_no unique in this situation !

Also in cases where you have VARCHAR2 columns, you can use MAX, MIN on them as aggregate functions along with group by to make a unique key in the query.

**Example:**

```
Select object_type, min(object_name) 
from user_objects group by object_type;
```

which will make the object_type unique & return only 1 corresponding object name for it.

So note that if there are duplicate's, in the end some records will be eliminated based on the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

> "But I did a group statement to make sure from_t.NAME is unique:"

But your query does not do that. It produces a set of distinct combinations of `(institution_cd,name,institution_status,country_cd)`. Clearly such a set could contain multiple recurrences of `name`, one for each different value of `country_cd`. As you have four elements in your key you are virtually guaranteeing that your set will have multiple occurrences of `name`.

You compound this with the `or` in the ON conditions, which means you trigger the UNMATCHED logic if `to_t.VENDOR_INSTITUTION_CD = from_t.INSTITUTION_CD` even though there is already a record in the target table where `to_t.INSTITUTION_CD = from_t.NAME`.

The problem is that the MERGE statement is atomic. The set of records coming from the USING subquery must contain unique keys. When Oracle finds a second occurrence of the same `name` in the result set it doesn't say, *I've already merged one of those, let's skip it.* It has to hurl ORA-00001 because there is no way for Oracle to know which record is apply, which combination of `(institution_cd,name,institution_status,country_cd)` is the correct one.

To solve this you need to change the USING query to produce a result set with unique keys. It's your data model, you understand its business rules, so you're in the position to rewrite it properly. But maybe something like this:

```
  select 
    name,
    max(institution_cd) as institution_cd,
    institution_status,
    max(country_cd) as country_cd
  from (
    institution uni
  where
    uni.institution_status = 'ACTIVE' and
    uni.country_cd is not null
  group by
    name,
    institution_status
  order by
    name  
) uni
```

Then you can simplify the MERGE ON clause to:

```
on
(
  to_t.INSTITUTION_CD = from_t.NAME
)
```

The use of `MAX()` in the subquery is an inelegant kludge. I hope you can apply better business rules.